# How to increase jupyter notebook max buffer size in google cloud AI platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-ml, gcp-ai-platform-notebook, gcp-ai-platform-training

I am running Jupyter notebook on Google Cloud Platform. I have a big pickeld Dataframe to read. Since default buffer size of Jupyter notebook is around 0.5 Gb, it crashes and restarts kernel. I have added `NotebookApp.max_buffer_size='my desired value'` inside the `jupyter_notebook_config.py` in the Compute Engine but still problem is there.

Comment: What is the Jupyter Machine Hardware settings  CPUs & RAM?

Comment: You can use `python3 -m pip install nbresuse` to get a jupyter notebook plugin to show memory consumption in the top right.

Answer (score 0):

I think resizing the instance is supposed to change memory limits, but I got same problem resizing to a bigger instance, here is my workaround:

I would recommend you save your work before trying this, just in case.

Jupyter runs as a service, so open its service config:

```sh
sudo vim /lib/systemd/system/jupyter.service;
```

You should see this config:

```
[Unit]
Description=Jupyter Notebook

[Service]
Type=simple
PIDFile=/run/jupyter.pid
MemoryHigh=34359738368
MemoryMax=34359738368
ExecStart=/bin/bash --login -c '/opt/conda/bin/jupyter lab --config=/home/jupyter/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py'
User=jupyter
Group=jupyter
WorkingDirectory=/home/jupyter
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Change MemoryHigh and MemoryMax to desired values in bytes.

Then:

```sh
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart jupyter
```

Wait a little for jupyter to restart and you should be good to go.